# Given a tree T = (V, E), find the direct path from a vertex v to vertex w

Tags: python, tree, pseudocode, direct-path

I'm stuck in my algorithm assignment which ask to find the direct path in a tree(V, E) with n vertices (acyclic indirect graph) from vertex v to vertex w in time complexity O(dist(v, w)). I have to find a preprocess (that runs in O(n)) to store some information such that I can achieve the time complexity O(dist(v, w)).

I'll need some idea to what store in the preprocess that will help later in the algorithm.

No full solution.

I already tried to store the possible path but to create a global Adj List I need quadratic time O(n^2).
Also Dijkstra run above the time complexity requested (and all routing algorithm for network).
Two nodes in a tree have a unique path.

Also tried to use dynamic programming to store all the path already discovered, but I think I get over the linear time. Running BFS and store all the previous path like: `(node, node) : next hop`

```
(A, B) : B and (B, A) : A
(B, C) : C (C, B): B (A, C) : B and (C, A): B
```

Therefore I'll need `(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + n - 1 + n) = n^2`

Answer (score 0):

If your network is a tree, then each vertex only has one "inbound" edge.  So you should try traversing the links from W to V (following the inbound edges) instead of the other way around.   This will give you the path in reverse order.  Store it in a list and invert it to produce the result.

Note that you may need to build a dictionary of vertices {child:parent} to do this if you don't already have a way to traverse the tree from bottom to top.  Building this dictionary will take O(E) time, then finding the path will take dist(V,W) time.